# Cannot change volume level on headphones

Tags: windows-10, audio

I noticed today that when I have headphones plugged in I cannot change volume level. It doesnt matter what level I set the volume I hear is always same. It is same even when I set 0.

[In image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuyYb.gif) you can see that when I set 0 level in windows settings the music still plays, when I set 100 level the music still plays at about the same level.

[image: sound settings]

How can I fix this?

Comment: The “VU meter” displayed in Settings is unrelated to the output volume you select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it, I did two things:

### First

open "Dell command update"[image: Dell Command Update utility] and click on customize [image] and select only Recommended -> Dell Command Update

### Second

[image: device manager]

open device manager and uninstall any unknown device or any other that is not familiar to you In my case there has been some NC50 drivers that I didnt know, I uninstalled both

I restarted computer after both steps and now it works :).

Comment: Even though you have given your own answer, you should still mark the question as solved, for the benefit of others.

Answer (score -1):

Have you read the text below the device selection?

Pretty much self-explanatory.

Not familiar with Windows 10, but in general, 
most operating systems employ some kind of software mixing between applications, and my guess is that in Win 10, this is more elaborate.

If you right click on the system tray speaker icon, you *should* be able to get that application mixer. Try fiddling those buttons.

My conclusion is based on the fact that most of the control panels in Windows 10 are very abstract, and under the hood, things work a bit different. Windows 10 gives quite a false sense of simplicity.

Comment: thanks but it worked before, anyway I tried to set custom levels for applications but it didnt worked neither

Comment: what about your keyboard volume up/down keys? also, what happens when you use the volume slider in the music player?

Comment: keyboard didnt worked, but youtube volume settings was working ... I uninstalled unknown devices and now it works, thanks

Comment: Well, you figured it out then... beats me. I also had variable behavior with various devices, e.g. reacting or not reacting to volume control. Sometimes the reason is that the slider needs to pickup the current value before applying the gain. But that's not the case here. FYI, it is better to disable unknown devices, Win might auto-install them later on.

Comment: Your guess is wrong btw, the software mixing of Windows came in late (most other OS have had this feature for a *very* long time) and is pretty naïve by modern standards. For instance, it is unable to send the output of an application to multiple devices, or to feed the output of one application as the input of another.